# How to store a class of type ZXing.Result in SQLite table?

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms, zxing

I am developing a Xamarin.Forms application and using SQLite to store data.

I want to store the instance of the ZXing.Result class in my database table. However, SQLite does not allow this. Is there any way to do this? (I am using ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms NuGet package)

Like this.

```cs
    public class Barcode
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public ZXing.Result ScannerResult { get; set; }
        public bool IsFavourite { get; set; }
        public string TypeofBarcode { get; set; }
        public DateTime RegistrationDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    }
```

Comment: do you need the entire Result object, or just the string value of the scanned barcode?

Comment: I need all Result object.

Comment: then you need to build a table structure that models Result and all of it's properties.  Alternately, you could serialize Result to json and store it as a string in your table

Comment: May you show me an example?

Comment: I really suggest you look at the properties of the Result object and pick the ones you actually need instead of trying to store the entire Result object